# Network analysis in shiny R

Tags: r

I have been working on creating a dashboard in R to display a reactive table output and network graph to be displayed. My data has 5 columns DT_TRX (date), DS_CUSTOMERNAME, BENEFICIARY, AMOUNT, MODE. The network graph should show the link between DS_CUSTOMERNAME sending money to BENEFICIARY.

The filters are DS_CUSTOMERNAME and DT_TRX. I have been able to get the table output but i am unable to add the reactive network graph as per the selected DS_CUSTOMERNAME and DT_TRX.

My code so far is as shown below:

```
#link_data <- readRDS("~/E/Link Analysis/link_data.rds")
str(link_data)
link_data$DT_REQUEST = ymd(link_data$DT_REQUEST)
link_data$STATUS [link_data$STATUS == 1]<- "EFTS"
link_data$STATUS [link_data$STATUS == 2]<- "Cheque"
link_data$STATUS [link_data$STATUS == 3]<- "RTGS"
link_data$STATUS = factor(link_data$STATUS)
colnames(link_data) = c("DT_TRX", "BENEFICIARY",
 "AMOUNT", "DS_CUSTOMERNAME", "DS_DEPARTMENT", "MODE")
link_data$BENEFICIARY = as.character(link_data$BENEFICIARY)
link_data$DS_CUSTOMERNAME = as.character(link_data$DS_CUSTOMERNAME)
link_data = na.omit(link_data)
link_data$DT_TRX = factor(link_data$DT_TRX)
#App

ui = dashboardPage(skin = "blue",

                   dashboardHeader(title = "LINK ANALYSIS"),

                   #SideBar

                   dashboardSidebar(

                     sidebarMenu (

                       menuItem ( "MY DASHBOARD" , tabName = "DASHBOARD" ,

                                  icon = icon ( "dashboard" )),

                       width = 200,

                       selectInput("DS_DEPARTMENT",
                        label = em("SELECT DEPARTMENT",
                        style = "text-align:center;
                       color:#FFA319; font-size:100%"),

                       unique(link_data$DS_DEPARTMENT),
                      selected = 'CORPORATE BANKING'),

                       selectInput('DS_CUSTOMERNAME',
                          em('CHOOSE A CUSTOMER NAME'
                         ,style = "text-align:center;
                        color:#FFA319; font-size:100%"),"",

                                   selectize = FALSE, selected = ''),

                       dateRangeInput('DT_TRX',

                          label = em('DATE RANGE INPUT: dd/mm/yyyy'
                                 , style = "text-align:center;
                                  color:#FFA319; font-size:100%"),

                                      start = Sys.Date() -365,

                                      end = Sys.Date() -1,

                                      format = "dd/mm/yyyy")

                     )

                   ),

                   #Body

                   dashboardBody (

                     column(width = 12,

                       h5(strong("LINK ANALYSIS DATA"
                         ,style = "text-align:right;color
                        :darkblue; font-size:100%")),
                      div(tableOutput("table1")
                       , style = "font-size:80%",collapsible = TRUE)),

                     fluidPage(

                       visNetworkOutput("network"),

                       verbatimTextOutput("shiny_return"))

                   )
)
server = function(input, output, session){
DS_DEPARTMENT = reactive({     input$DS_DEPARTMENT   })
DS_CUSTOMERNAME = reactive({input$DS_CUSTOMERNAME   })

  MODE = reactive({input$MODE})

  outvar = reactive({     
   mm = link_data$DS_CUSTOMERNAME[link_data$DS_DEPARTMENT
    == DS_DEPARTMENT ()]     unique (mm)   })

  output$DT_TRXText = renderText({     
   paste( "input$DT_TRX is",
   paste(as.character(input$DT_TRX), collapse = "to"))   })

  observe({     
   updateSelectInput(session, "DS_CUSTOMERNAME",
   choices = outvar())   })

  observe({     updateDateRangeInput(
   session, inputId = "DT_TRX")   })

  best = reactive({     
   filter(link_data, DS_DEPARTMENT == DS_DEPARTMENT (),
   DS_CUSTOMERNAME == DS_CUSTOMERNAME (),
   as.Date(link_data$DT_TRX) >= input$DT_TRX [1] 
   & as.Date(link_data$DT_TRX) <= input$DT_TRX [2])   })

  output$table1 <- renderTable(best(), include.rownames = FALSE)

  color = c('#75a3a3','#999966','#79a6d2','#c68c53')

  observeEvent(input$createNetwork,{   #Nodes   sources <- best() %>%
  distinct(DS_CUSTOMERNAME) %>%
  rename(label = DS_CUSTOMERNAME)   destinations <- best() %>%
  distinct(BENEFICIARY) %>%
  rename(label = BENEFICIARY)   nodes <- full_join(sources,
   destinations, by = "label")   #Edges
  per_route <- best() %>%     
  group_by(DS_CUSTOMERNAME, BENEFICIARY) %>%
  summarise(weight = n()) %>%
  ungroup()   per_route   edges <- per_route %>%
  left_join(nodes, by = c("DS_CUSTOMERNAME" = "label")) %>% 
  rename(from = id)   edges <- edges %>%     left_join(nodes,
  by = c("BENEFICIARY" = "label")) %>%
 rename(to = id)   edges <- select(edges, from, to, weight)   }) }



shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want a reactive table output and a reactive network graph which is in line with what a person has selected as the DT_TRX and DS_CUSTOMERNAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#App
ui = dashboardPage(skin = "red", 
                   dashboardHeader(title = "LINK ANALYSIS"), 

                   #SideBar
                   dashboardSidebar(
                     sidebarMenu (
                       menuItem ( "MY DASHBOARD" , 
                                  tabName = "DASHBOARD" ,
                                  icon = icon ( "dashboard" )),
                       width = 200,
                       selectInput("DS_DEPARTMENT", 
                                   label = em("SELECT DEPARTMENT", 
                                              style = "text-align:center; color:#FFA319; font-size:100%"),
                                   unique(link_data$DS_DEPARTMENT),
                                   selected = 'CORPORATE BANKING'),

                       selectInput('DS_CUSTOMERNAME',
                                   em('CHOOSE A CUSTOMER NAME', 
                                      style = "text-align:center; color:#FFA319; font-size:100%"),
                                   "",
                                   selectize = FALSE, 
                                   selected = ''),

                       dateRangeInput('DT_TRX', 
                                      label = em('DATE RANGE INPUT: dd/mm/yyyy', 
                                                 style = "text-align:center; color:#FFA319; font-size:100%"),
                                      start = Sys.Date() %m-% months(6),
                                      end = Sys.Date() -1,
                                      format = "dd/mm/yyyy")
                     )
                   ),

                   #Body
                   dashboardBody (
                     column(width = 12,

                            h5(strong("LINK ANALYSIS DATA",
                                      style = "text-align:right;color:darkblue; font-size:100%")),

                            div(tableOutput("table1"), 
                                style = "font-size:80%",collapsible = TRUE)),
                     fluidPage(
                       theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                       titlePanel("Network Visualization App"),
                       sidebarLayout(
                         sidebarPanel(             
                         ),
                         mainPanel(

                           h3("Network Visualization"),
                           visNetworkOutput("plot2"),
                           dataTableOutput("nodes_data_from_shiny"),
                           uiOutput('dt_UI'))))
                   )
)



server = function(input, output, session){

  DS_DEPARTMENT = reactive({
    input$DS_DEPARTMENT
  })

  DS_CUSTOMERNAME = reactive({
    input$DS_CUSTOMERNAME
  })

  MODE =  reactive({
    input$MODE
  })

  outvar = reactive({
    mm = link_data$DS_CUSTOMERNAME[link_data$DS_DEPARTMENT == DS_DEPARTMENT ()]
    unique (mm)
  })

  output$DT_TRXText = renderText({
    paste( "input$DT_TRX is",
           paste(as.character(input$DT_TRX), collapse = "to"))
  })


  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "DS_CUSTOMERNAME",
                      choices = outvar())
  })

  observe({
    updateDateRangeInput(
      session, inputId = "DT_TRX")
  })

  best = reactive({
    filter(link_data, DS_DEPARTMENT == DS_DEPARTMENT (), DS_CUSTOMERNAME == DS_CUSTOMERNAME (), 
           as.Date(link_data$DT_TRX) >= input$DT_TRX [1] & as.Date(link_data$DT_TRX) <= input$DT_TRX [2]) 
  })


  output$table1 <- renderTable(best(), include.rownames = FALSE)

  color = c('#75a3a3','#999966','#79a6d2','#c68c53')

  output$plot2 <- renderVisNetwork ({
    my_df = best()

    #Nodes
    sources <- my_df %>%
      distinct(DS_CUSTOMERNAME) %>%
      rename(label = DS_CUSTOMERNAME)

    destinations <- my_df %>%
      distinct(BENEFICIARY) %>%
      rename(label = BENEFICIARY)

    nodes <- full_join(sources, destinations, by = "label")

    nodes <- nodes %>% rowid_to_column("id")

    #--------------------------edges------------------------
    per_route <- my_df %>%  
      group_by(DS_CUSTOMERNAME, BENEFICIARY) %>%
      summarise(weight = n()) %>% 
      ungroup()
    per_route

    edges <- per_route %>% 
      left_join(nodes, by = c("DS_CUSTOMERNAME" = "label")) %>% 
      rename(from = id)

    edges <- edges %>% 
      left_join(nodes, by = c("BENEFICIARY" = "label")) %>% 
      rename(to = id)

    visNetwork (nodes,edges) %>% 
      visEvents (select = "function(nodes) {
                 Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
                 ;}") %>%

      visOptions(highlightNearest = T, nodesIdSelection = T) %>%

      # Specify that hover interaction and on-screen button navigations are active
      visInteraction(hover = T, navigationButtons = T) %>%

      visIgraphLayout()

})

  myNode <- reactiveValues(selected = '')

  observeEvent(input$current_node_id, {
    myNode$selected <<- input$current_node_id
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    edges [which (myNode$selected == edge$from),]
  })

  output$dt_UI <- renderUI ({
    if(nrow (edges [which(myNode$selected == edges$from),]) !=0){
      dataTableOutput('table')
    } else{}

  }) 

  }

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```